# how can i run batches in thread worker parallel

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, threadpool, python-multithreading

any help please how can i do this process and run batch en parallel with multiprocessing.pool
I have a list of batches (20000 items) splited into multiple batches one batch 2000,
batch_size = 2000
i use multiprocessing.pool

```
# This loop needs to be parallelized
for batch_index, batched_payloads in enumerate(frappe.utils.create_batch(payloads, batch_size)):
            for i, payload in enumerate(batched_payloads):
                # Do something
                    continue
                try:
                    doc = self.process_doc(doc)
                    # Do something
                    frappe.db.commit()
                except Exception:
                    frappe.db.rollback()
```

Comment: while you can make it run in parallel, you need to make sure whatever you are calling can safely be called in parallel, and shared database connections usually aren't safe, so you will have to think if a race condition can result in data corruption or not for your code, it's simple to throw in a line of code to parallelize it in two minutes then spend the next few weeks fixing the data corruption because of it, or the next few months trying to figure out where the corruption happened

Comment: I need to know just how can i parallelize it

Answer (score 0):

One solution is use https://github.com/classner/pymp for multiprocessing and parallel processing